# In PHP should I use a regular expression to match on this or something else?

Tags: php, string, expression, match

I need to be able to check if a variable contains the first part of a string. For example, "foobaz xy". Everything after "foobaz xy" can be ignored for the match. This has to be case insensitive too and there must be a space between foobaz and xy. Is there already a built-in function in PHP which handles this, or is a regular expression required to do this? Last and not the least, if more than one method which has a faster execution time? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

There is no built-in function for it, but there is a tiny workaround which can achieve the same thing. Check the following example:

```
$string = "foobaz xyewew";
if (stripos($string, "foobaz xy") === 0) {
    echo "It starts with foobaz xy";
}
```

Comment: I'm still new here, but if I could I would vote this a thumbs up! Thanks so much for your help. I was able to take this code and make a small function out of it which returns either TRUE or FALSE. This will help me finish my program and make it simpler!

Answer (score 0):

As for the case insensitive issue, you can copy the new string to another and convert it in all lower case, that would make it case insensitive.

Lets say string A= foobaz xy and b=sth sth sth then all you need to do is to take a substring of string b which will always be the size of foobaz xy, hence, if b is less than foobaz xy in character count, it will be discounted automatically. If not, then you need to compare the substring to the constant string A and that will solve the problem.

[see php substring here:](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)

[see strcmp here to compare the substring and your string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php)
[see here to convert a string into all lowercase](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php)

Answer (score 0):

Fastest way to check that:

```
$variable  = "FooBaz xy test string";
$isContain = strpos(strlower($variable, "foobaz xy")) === 0;
```

Comment: @invisal solution is better, forgot about stripos function

Answer (score 0):

The first answer is correct, more info on http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php. Always remember that it is a bad practice to use regular expressions in simple string checking.

Comment: Thank you. I had a feeling it wasn't a good idea, which is why I posted to ask and I'm glad I did!